# Java FX "The method setDisabled(boolean) from the type Node is not visible"

Tags: java, javafx

```
    package application;

    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;

    public class MainWindowController {

    public Main main;
    @FXML
    public Button gameStart;

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.main = main;
    }

     @FXML
     private void gameStart(ActionEvent event) {
         // Button was clicked, do something...
        System.out.println("Button has been clicked");
        gameStart.setDisabled(true);
     }

}
```

Why do I always get the error message:
The method setDisabled(boolean) from the type Node is not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong property. Use this one (without the "d" at the end.)

```
gameStart.setDisable(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

1.use setDisable(true).

2."Disable" takes into consideration only the disabled state of this particular node whereas "Disabled" takes into consideration the disabled state if its parents as well.

3.visit
https://books.google.co.in/books?id=c1Iz7eofFdUC&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=The+method+setDisabled(boolean)+from+the+type+Node+is+not+visible&source=bl&ots=z83qATJxIR&sig=b5YIJcXezdEB3-ygF2P12qa2LIY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU0KCnv9rSAhUMpo8KHTY0Aw0Q6AEIMTAE#v=onepage&q=The%20method%20setDisabled(boolean)%20from%20the%20type%20Node%20is%20not%20visible&f=false